# MySQL MONTHNAME - SELECT column as MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

Tags: mysql

MySQL MONTHNAME - SELECT column as MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

It's all in the title of the question.

I need to select a column header as the name of the month(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) but I am getting a syntax error: unexpected '('.

Anyone got any ideas?  I've searched the net for a while on this one and cant find any related examples or questions.

Here's part of the SQL query

```html
SELECT
   @STATEVAR:=e.ADDRESS4 AS 'STATE',
   (SELECT TRUNCATE(SUM(b.LINETOTAL), 2) FROM
    DATA_WH.SALESORD_HDR a
    LEFT JOIN DATA_WH.SALESORD_LINES b
    ON a.SEQNO = b.HDR_SEQNO
     LEFT JOIN DATA_WH.STOCK_ITEMS c
     ON b.STOCKCODE = c.STOCKCODE
      LEFT JOIN DATA_WH.STOCK_GROUPS d
      ON c.STOCKGROUP = d.GROUPNO
       LEFT JOIN DATA_WH.DR_ACCS e
       ON a.ACCNO = e.ACCNO
    WHERE
     b.STOCKCODE <> '' AND a.STATUS = '2' AND a.ACCNO <> '1040' AND MONTH(a.ORDERDATE) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND YEAR(a.ORDERDATE) = YEAR(NOW())
     AND e.ADDRESS4 = @STATEVAR) 
   AS  MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many records does this query return?

Comment: Well it only returns the summed sales total for each STATE that is in the resultset, so anywhere between 15 and 20.  You can see what I'm trying to do yes?  I'm trying to grab the month sales total for each state in a single SQL so that I can reference that from an EXCEL data connection without having to massage the result or anything.

Comment: There's probably a much better way to go about this and I am over complicating it...

Comment: Create a new column for the month name alias, then pivot the result by month.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen I've never used a pivot query in SQL, something to get my head around but I will give it a shot.  Thanks, appreicate the suggestion!  The data is going to be reused continually so I might just build a stored procedure to build a table and put the data in there...  Thanks